# I need to find a selector for my UIButton on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

I have searched for days but i still cannot find the selector for a UIButton. help!

in my view controller m.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
-(IBAction)answer1:(id)sender{
l.text = @"Try again";
}

-(IBAction)answer2:(id)sender{
label.text = @"Yes congratulations";

}

-(IBAction)answer3:(id)sender;{
s.text = @"Try again";
}
-(IBAction)answer3:(id)sender;{
x.text = @"Try again";
}
-(IBAction)button1:(id)sender{
y.(   ) = self.try Again;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

my view controller h.

```
     IBOutlet UILabel *label;

   IBOutlet UILabel *s;
IBOutlet UILabel *l;
IBOutlet UILabel *x;

IBOutlet UIButton *y;

}

-(IBAction)answer1:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)answer2:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)answer3:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)answer4:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)button1:(id)sender;

@end
```

i want to know where i can fill in the selector space(the space in brackets) please tell me if you know!

Comment: by the way, the brackets space is right after the y "thing"

Comment: Unclear. What are you _ultimately_ trying to do?

Comment: `[y setTitle:@"sometext" forState:UIControlStateNormal];` ?

Comment: I'm supposed to do a quiz app